# Rails generates unwanted whitespace between partials

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, high-voltage

I'm developing a Rails application using `bootstrap-sass` and `high_voltage`.

I have a navbar partial in `views/application/_navbar.html.erb` which I'm rendering in the `application.html.erb` layout view. This, however, causes a `&#65279;` to appear **between the navbar and the current view**, which breaks my layout. This occurs in any view in the application.

Relevant code in `application.html.erb`:

```
<body>
  <%= render 'navbar' %>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'footer' %>
</body>
```

The navbar is just a default Bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar.

I've tried to remove the whitespace between the `render` calls, as follows:

`<body><%= render 'navbar' %><%= yield %><%= render 'footer' %></body>`

but to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: screenshot of the Chrome devtools**

[image: Screengrab]

Comment: You should inspect the page in the browser and figure out what CSS rules are adding margins/paddings, rails will not "add whitespace" by itself.

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I know how css works. Here is the outputted HTML since you don't seem to believe me:

`</div></nav>&#65279;<section class="container-fluid carousel-wrapper">`.

Comment: I would check your JS and what you're yielding. What is carousel-wrapper? Try to wrap the yield block into a "container" div and see if it still appears between the nav and the new container

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer Thanks. I'm not sure how JS could effect this problem? The non-breaking space now appears between the starting `<div>` and the beginning of the view partial.

Comment: If you're loading some JS libs/plugins/etc it might be trying to do something with the container and due to some reason adding that text node right before the container it should affect, probably to help with displaying something? I would say it's something like that.

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I tried viewing the page with Javascript disabled, but that unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I'm using now is to just strip the space from the page using javascript (jQuery in my case):

`$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/\uFEFF/, ''));`